# My kable table will not export as an image

Tags: r, data-visualization, kable

I am having trouble exporting a table I made in R.  I think it may be too large.  The original dataframe cv_exp is 45 by 10, how can I export the table from R?  Exporting it as an image only returns half the file.  I have saved it as a webpage, should I try converting it to pdf or something so i can include it in reports for documents?  How could I get it as a jpeg or png for including in a PowerPoint presentation.

```
male_cv_exp = cv_exp
row.names(male_cv_exp)[c(5,6,25, 33, 34, 35, 40, 43)] <- paste0(row.names(male_cv_exp)[c(5,6,25, 33, 34, 35, 40, 43)],
                                                                footnote_marker_symbol(2))
kbl(male_cv_exp, align ="c", escape = F,
    col.names = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female"),
    caption = " Coefficient of Variation of Exposure Variables ") %>%
  kable_classic() %>%
  add_header_above(c("Exposures" = 1, "White" = 2, "Black" = 2, "Hispanic" = 2, "Asian" = 2, "Other" = 2)) %>%
  footnote(symbol = " Calculated as the frequency of a true answer in each group. ",
           symbol_title = "Binary Variable: ",
           footnote_as_chunk = T,
           symbol_manual = footnote_marker_symbol(2))
```

Comment: All of that is going to depend on context and what you need to be able to do with the table. I'm confused because you've named several different outputs (webpage, pdf, image file, powerpoint) that may have different uses. I also don't see what you've done to export it as an image, and because we don't have any of your data, we can't run your code

Comment: I need it for powerpoint to make into presentation and I need it for pdf.  Currently it is in html.  Is that the problem?  Do I need to change the code for each of those uses?

I think the simplest solution would be to make it into an image file then I could just copy and paste it as needed.

Comment: That's why I'm saying it depends. If you want the text to be kept as text, use something other than an image. If you want an image, you need a function that exports images—I think the `gt` package does this. But right now you're saying you exported it as an image, but there isn't code here that would do that, just code that would print a table in a markdown, html, or Latex format depending on the document your code is in

Comment: I did a sort of cheap work around, I exported it as html then zoomed out and prt scrn then cropped it in paint,  I will check out the gt package later.  Thanks for pointing me to it.  Could you post it as an answer so I can close this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think the question is specific enough to want to answer it. You could just close it though if that's what you want to do, or edit to make it more clear and reproducible. I'm voting to close

Comment: I voted to close as well